# Why and how does this "for..in" statement work?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I'm learning JavaScript via CodeCademy and am on the "Contact List" project; specifically, "Search For A Friend" lesson. It has me learning how Objects work and how to look within them.

The demonstrated code is as follows:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};

var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
};

list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

So I understand that `friends` is an object and `bill` and `steve` are objects within `friends`. What I don't understand is how `list` and `search` functions look inside `friends`. I see that it uses a `for/in` loop... but after learning loops, I see no conditions and I see no iteration mechanism. I have no concept on how this `for/in` is actually working. Maybe if someone could provide an alternate of equivalent syntax; perhaps, even, if someone can explain in colloquial English **why/how** `for/in` works?

Thank you!

NOTE: Tagging as Language-Agnostic, because it's a higher-level programming/conceptual question, even if the syntax here is JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really an equivalent alternate syntax; `for (x in y)` *is* the iteration mechanism.

It's *analogous* to

```
for ( x = 0; x < somearray.length; ++x )
```

in that it sets `x` to each index in turn. But since JS objects are, by definition, unordered, there's no guarantee you'll get the indices in any particular sequence.

There are no conditions. You'll hit every index. It's a *different* construct.

So if we have:

```
var obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
```

and say:

```
for ( var x in obj )
{
  console.log( x + ": " + obj[x] );   // prints "a: 1", etc.
}
```

then exactly once in that loop, `x` == "a". Exactly once, `x` == "b". Exactly once, `x` == "c". Only those, in no specified order.

Comment: You could have something like `Object.keys(obj).forEach(...);` which is equivalent to a `for in` loop.

Comment: So what you're saying is that in `for (var x in obj)`, `x` corresponds to the keys `a`,`b`, etc? And that when I run a `for...in` loop, it iterates and in each iteration it assigns `x=a`,`x=b`, etc?

EDIT: Also, that `obj[x]` refers to the keys `a`,`b`, etc and returns the values (`1`,`2`, etc)?

Comment: Yes. When `x == 'a'`, `obj[x] == obj['a']`, which in the example is equal to `1`

Answer (score 1):

In short, your `for(var prop in obj)`, it is equivalent to while `obj` has items, get `prop` and do something with it (in plain English). So the loop will stop when there are no other "props" to be taken from "obj".

Here is a detailed explanation of the for/in loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

In your case for(var prop in friends) "prop" represents the keys. After you can use something like friends[prop].anyProperty.

It would be more meaningful to use:

```
 for(var key in friends)
```

About "for in" :

From Douglas Crockford's **"Javascript The Good Parts"** book :

The for in statement can loop over all of the property names in an object. The enumeration
will include all of the properties—including functions and prototype properties
that you might not be interested in—so it is necessary to filter out the values
youdon’t want. The most common filters are the hasOwnProperty method and using
typeof to exclude functions:

```
var name;
for (name in another_stooge) {
 if (typeof another_stooge[name] !== 'function') {
   document.writeln(name + ': ' + another_stooge[name]);
 }
}
```

There is no guarantee on the order of the names, so be prepared for the names to
appear in any order. If you want to assure that the properties appear in a particular
order, it is best to avoid the for in statement entirely and instead make an array containing
the names of the properties in the correct order:

```
var i;
var properties = [
  'first-name',
  'middle-name',
  'last-name',
  'profession'
];


for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i += 1) {
  document.writeln(properties[i] + ': ' +
  another_stooge[properties[i]]);
}
```

By using for instead of for in, we were able to get the properties we wanted without
worrying about what might be dredged up from the prototype chain, and we got
them in the correct order.